# LINQ query works in LINQPad, but not in VS

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework, currently getting this when it hits the last line :

> The methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final
>   query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this
>   instance instead.

My query is:

```
 var orderitems =
   from orderItem in db.Order_ProductItem
   join style in db.Products_Styles on orderItem.Style equals style.Index
   where orderItem.SalesOrderID == salesOrderId && 
        (orderItem.IsDeleted==null || orderItem.IsDeleted.Value == false)
   group new { orderItem, style } by orderItem.FrameNo into grp
   select new OrderItemModel
   {
       FrameNo = grp.Key,
       //Count = grp.Select(x => x.orderItem.FrameNo).Count(),
       TotalCost = grp.Sum(x => x.orderItem.CostPrice),
       OverAllWidth = grp.Single(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallWidth,
       OverAllHeight = grp.Single(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallHeight,
       Name = grp.Select(x => x.style.Name).First(),
       ImagePath = grp.Select(x => x.style.External_Image_Path).First()
   };

var orders =  orderitems.ToList();
```

Seems to work okay in LINQPad/Linq to SQL....

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried what the error message says?

Comment: Are you loading your DbContext assembly into Linqpad, or just pointing Linqpad at your database to run the query? Linqpad uses Linq-to-SQL by default which does not execute queries the same as Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated like so, and it works now.... still confused as to why it was dumping it fine in LINQPad....

```
var orderitems =
                   from orderItem in db.Order_ProductItem
                   join style in db.Products_Styles on orderItem.Style equals style.Index
                   where orderItem.SalesOrderID == salesOrderId && (orderItem.IsDeleted==null || orderItem.IsDeleted.Value == false)
                   group new { orderItem, style } by orderItem.FrameNo into grp
                   select new OrderItemModel
                   {
                       FrameNo = grp.Key,
                       //Count = grp.Select(x => x.orderItem.FrameNo).Count(),
                       TotalCost = grp.Sum(x => x.orderItem.CostPrice),
                       OverAllWidth = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallWidth,
                       OverAllHeight = grp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallHeight,
                       Name = grp.FirstOrDefault().style.Name,//.FirstOrDefault(),
                       ImagePath = grp.FirstOrDefault().style.External_Image_Path//x => x.style.External_Image_Path)//.FirstOrDefault()
                   };
                //var count = orderitems.Count();


                var orders =  orderitems.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `Single()` and `First()`.

```
OverAllWidth = grp.Single(x => x.orderItem.HardwareType == 3).orderItem.OverallWidth
```

This would throw an exception, if the query would return more then one result, which is totally possible, because there could be more then one item returned which is of HadwareType 3. Single() expects excactly one return value

Use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` instead. If more then one resultset is returned it will take the first one.

Comment: Jon Skeet to the rescue?

Comment: Well, I'd start with verifying what SQL is generated in case of Linq to SQL and EF. Maybe answer would become clear :)

Comment: I have just tested a grouping and then a Name = `Select(p => p.Single(boolexpresision))` on my northwind database with products table and I ran into an InvalidOperationException. If there is one result per Grouping it works, f.e. UnitPrice == 10, but if I go Unitprice != null, an exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when LINQpad was connected to the database directly. If you connect LINQpad to your Entity Framework Assembly rather than the database, the behaviour of LINQpad and Visual Studio is closer to identical.
To connect to the Entity Framework Assembly, I followed this page:
https://www.vitoshacademy.com/c-entity-framework-using-linqpad5-for-queries-just-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the query is executing the same data source? As others have noted, Single will toss an exception if the sequence returned by the query does not have exactly one element.